# Prove that $f:X\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous iff it maps equivalent sequences onto equivalent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

Let $X$ be a subset of $\Bbb{R}$, and let $f:X\to\Bbb{R}$ be a function. Then the following two statements are logically equivalent:

(a) $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X$.

(b) Whenever $(x_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $(y_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ are two equivalent sequences consisting of elements of $X$, the sequences $(f(x_{n}))_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $(f(y_{n}))_{n=0}^{\infty}$ are also equivalent.

**My solution (Edit)**

I am mainly interested in the implication $(b)\Rightarrow(a)$.

Let us suppose that $(b)$ holds and $(a)$ does not hold.

The following statements are equivalent

- $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous
- for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x,y\in X$,
  \begin{align*}
  |x - y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(y)| \leq \varepsilon
  \end{align*}

Based on it, we are going to demonstrate the proposed statement by contradiction.

In other words, let us assume there exists a $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ there are $x,y\in X$
\begin{align*}
(|x - y| < \delta)\wedge (|f(x) - f(y)| > \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

In particular, for each $\delta = 1/n$, there are $x_{n},y_{n}\in X$ satisfying
\begin{align*}
|x_{n} - y_{n}| \leq 1/n\quad\wedge\quad|f(x_{n}) - f(y_{n})| > \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Taking the limit, we get that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(x_{n} - y_{n}) = 0$, but $f(x_{n})$ and $f(y_{n})$ are not equivalent, contradicting the given assumption.

Could someone help me to grasp this difference properly?

Comment: The definition of uniform continuity is: for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x,y$ if $|x - y| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(y)|<\epsilon$

To negate this you flip the quantifiers and negate the implication inside: there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$ there exists $x,y$ such that $|x - y| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(y)| \geq \epsilon$.

I believe this is what you were using.

Comment: it should be $|f(x) - f(y)| \ge \varepsilon$ instead of $>\varepsilon$ (and so on). What do you mean by "deny the definition of uniform continuity"? You have proved that if $f$ is not uniformly continuous, then there exists a pair of equivalent sequences whose image is not equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I forgot to edit this part. I have removed it.